# Swift : Register notifications from Parse.com doesn't stay enable

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I've configured my program to receive notification from Parse and I've enabled it with these lines :

```
var pushSettings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings)

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

The declaration is in the

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

from my appDelegate, but when I close my program and relaunch it, all of the parameters are reset and I get them "off"

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by off?

Comment: I will try with this link because i'm not able to post an image here a this time http://hpics.li/b8b9503
Those 2 switch reset both when i restart my app..

Comment: I'd try deleting the app then running it again. Is it the fact you cant set the switch?

Comment: I can set the switch when i go in my IPhone's parameters, but they are reset to "off" when the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called.